# Wifi connecting issue in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: networking, wireless

I am having issue with wifi. I have encrypted whole disk while installed Ubuntu 16.04. I am not able to connect to wifi or LAN. I don't remember exactly but when I am updating manually with "sudo apt-get update", it asking me the encrypted partition password.

Comment: Please run the script that is in the accepted answer in the link below so we may see the information needed to help diagnose the issue.
<http://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-
what-can-i-do>

Comment: I am not able to put whole out here. How to do so?

Comment: Post the results here http://pastebin.com/

Comment: http://pastebin.com/iwitLXCF

Comment: Are you sure it is not asking for the wifi password? What network are you trying to connect too?

Comment: It is asking for password but not connecting. I have observed that even in automatic software update, it is asking for password for encrypted partition. Previously it was not asked in software update or upgrade.

Comment: Yes, it is asking for wifi password but after that it is not connecting. Even the LAN is also not connecting. When I restart my laptop, ethernet port is not identified but if I connect LAN from another port in switch, it's get connected and again connecting to my regular LAN port, it got connected.

Comment: We are only dealing with the wifi issue in this question, we still need to know what is the name of the network you are trying to connect too please?

Comment: I am connecting to Breaker1 network